# Microsoft Japanese IME being useless

Tags: input-languages, ime, japanese

I'm using the Microsoft Japanese IME on Windows 10. Sometimes it's strangely useless with its suggestions, for instance I'm trying to type 捕る:

[image]

Even if I tab through the entire list, 捕る is nowhere to be found, even though it's a very common word and exactly matches what I typed. I could add it manually, but is there possibly something misconfigured with my IME? Is it just bad like this for everybody?

Comment: Which version of Windows? Check if you are in Kana/Hiragana/Kanji modes. From the list of suggesstions, it looks like you may be in kana/katakana mode.

Comment: Windows 10, input mode is romaji.

Answer (score 1):

Are you typing とる and then pressing the `tab` key once immediately?  It's interesting, because when I do this on Notepad on Windows 10 Pro, I don't get the same results as in your screenshot.

[image: Toru1]

However, if you type in とる and press the `space` key twice, you get another set of results, one of which 捕る is included.

[image: Toru2]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know you could do that! Though I've started using the Google IME since and I find it much better so far.